# Android app work fine in Android studio but crash when i download from play store

Tags: android, google-play

Android App Working fine when i run from Android Studio But when i try to download and run from play-store first show app crash then again open start working fine
[Logcat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8L1j.jpg)

Comment: Please post the crash log that you see in your logcat.

Comment: have you tried a release build locally before deploying signed apk to the store? It's very likely a proguard/minify issue.

Comment: if your app uses permissions like fine location and you didnt include permision request from the user it might fail.try enabling the permsins from settings

Comment: No, i am just using Network Permission